# when execute on terminal mode, it's working fine but the same code is not working if I execute from the file e.g. xyz.py

Tags: python

In Python, I want to print 
"st" for dates '1 & 21"; 
"nd" for '2 & 22'; and 
"rd" for dates '3 & 23'.

I have coded and it's working very fine without any error when tested on terminal mode (Dos prompt).  But when I execute from the file e.g. xyz.py which includes the same line, it's not working.  When I double click the file name, it flashes and disappears and nothing is happening.  I am using Python 3.8. I have given the coding below

```
    from datetime import date, timedelta
    import time

    today = date.today().strftime('%d')
    day = date.today().strftime('%A')
    if day == 'Monday':
      joint = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th']
      //if date is between 11 and 19, put th
      if int(today) > 10 and int(today) < 20 :
        place = 0
    else :
      place = int(today)%10
    today = today + joint[place]
```

Comment: It probably runs fine but immediately closes the window after it has finished. Put input() at the end of the code so it stays open until you press a key.

Comment: Comments in Python are ```#``` not ```//```. Also, you may have indentation errors. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have a very simple mistake in line 5, comments in python start with # not with //. That could be an the error.
Secondly your Program is so fast that it closes immediately after executing. You could just add a delay in the end of your code. Then you would see the output.
For the delay you just need to import the time module.

```
from time import sleep
```

Then your code with the fixed comment and the delay.

```
today = date.today().strftime('%d')
day = date.today().strftime('%A')
if day == 'Monday':
    joint = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th']
    #if date is between 11 and 19, put th
    if int(today) > 10 and int(today) < 20 :
        place = 0
else :
    place = int(today)%10
    today = today + joint[place]
sleep(5) #sleeps 5 sec
```

Comment: No problem, could you please mark this question then as solved. Cheers!